# External domain in web app

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

After I got my domain CNAME changed to azure service, I have to associate the azure web app with the address. When I try to do it I get the exclamation mark indicating error, and when I try to check what it says, it does not display any information (not a single sign). Does anyone experienced similar problem, and can tell me what is happening.

[image: Here I upload the screenshot that shows the problem]

Comment: Isn't that a commercial service? Supported by some fairly large technology company? If THEY can't help you with this, then .. all hope may be lost!

Comment: When did you get the CNAME changed to azure service? Sometimes it takes time for it to propagate.

Comment: About 5 hours ago. May it take longer? What is interesting is the fact that when I try to access the site i get Web App not found message it it looks like it propagated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have in my current setup:

- A Record -> @ -> IP of my webapp
- CNAME -> awverify -> myapp.azurewebsites.net
- CNAME -> www -> myapp.azurewebsites.net

then in my azure domain settings, I added domain.com

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is good documentation that will walk you through this. Basically you create an A record for the domain you want to map and point it to Azure. You then also have to create "awverify" CNAME records to verify you own the domain name.

Note from link below:

> The propagation of the DNS entries takes up to 48 hours (sometimes longer). If you have configured everything correctly, you still need to wait for the propagation to succeed.

ref: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

***EDIT**
Here's what I have at my DNS Host...

- ALIAS -- domain.com -> azuresubdomain.azurewebsites.net
- CNAME -- awverify.domain.com -> awverify.azuresubdomain.azurewebsites.net
- TXT -- domain.com -> ALIAS for azuresubdomain.azurewebsites.net

Comment: But A record and CNAME is pointed to Azure. I guess I will check in two days than. If the problem is solved then, I will accept your answer. Still, lack of any message is just strange.

Comment: Ok so even after waiting two days the problem still exists, and again I don't know what is the cause of it, because the label is not simply there.